# SELECT all rows with a given ID if at least one of those rows has a given value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I have is a mySQL query that will select some drinks and return basic information about the drink, as well as a list of the ingredients of that particular drink, as well as the rating for the particular drink. I have 3 tables drinks, drinks_ratings, drinks_ing

So, my issue is that say I want to get information about drinks that contain vodka, and are in a highball glass I would run the query below...

It works, its just my issue is that it doesnt return ALL the ingredients back. For Example, if I return "randomDrinkName1" and it happened to have vodka and soda in it....when i get the information back it leaves out the soda because i said WHERE ing = voda, so I understand why this is happeneing...but Is there some other type of WHERE clause I can do to check if it has "vodka" and return it along with all the other ingredient information that might also be there?

I know I could just do a query before this query that gets be back ids that have vodka in them from my drinks_ing table.

But this seems like it could be bad idea ...like if there were 1000s of drinks with vodka in them just to do a query on a select with a 1000 OR statements.

I'm interested if there is a way i can easily do this all in one query. thanks!

```
select dIngs.id,
    dIngs.name,
    dIngs.descrip,
    dIngs.type,
    dIngs.ing,
    AVG(b.rating) as arating,
    COUNT(b.id) as tvotes
from (
    select a.id,
        a.name,
        a.descrip,
        a.type,
        concat (
            '[',
            GROUP_CONCAT('{\"ing\":', c.ing, ',\"parts\":', c.parts, '}'),
            ']'
            ) ing
    from drinks a
    left join drinks_ing c on a.id = c.did
    where c.ing = "vodka"
        and a.type = "highball"
    group by a.id
    ) dIngs
left join drinks_ratings b on dIngs.id = b.id
group by dIngs.id
order by arating desc,
    tvotes desc LIMIT 0,
    50;
```

edit:
to illustrate a result that I would want to get is like this:

```
           [0]
              descrip = "the description text will be here"
              arating = 0
              id = 4
              ing = [ {"ing": "vodka", "parts": 4}, {"ing": "soda", "parts": 2}, {"ing": "sprite", "parts": 2} ]
              name = "awesomeDrink"
              type = "highball"
              tvotes = 0
```

but what im actually getting back just includes the vodka ing because thats what i was checking for

```
           [0]
              descrip = "the description text will be here"
              arating = 0
              id = 4
              ing = [ {"ing": "vodka", "parts": 4} ]
              name = "awesomeDrink"
              type = "highball"
              tvotes = 0
```

To be clear, if i dont supply something like  `where ing = vodka`, i get all the ingredients back just fine. thats not the issue....

I need it to just check if one of the potential ingredients happens to be vodka, then basically return all the ing data...and if vodka isn't a potential ingredient, ignore that drink and NOT return it.

edit:
what my tables look like..

```
drinks_ing
---------------
did (which is the drink id its associated with)
id (the id of the ingredient aka "vodka")
parts

drinks
---------------
id
name
description
type
timestamp

drinks_ratings
-----------------
id
userid
rating
timestamp
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data to work with.

Comment: Why... WHY are you building JSON in SQL instead of doing that in PHP with `json_encode()`?

Comment: Can you post your table create statement for the 3 tables and some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best approach may be to use a self join.  This is where you reference the same table twice, but by different names.  Roughly this would look like:

```
SELECT     d.stuff
FROM       drinks d
INNER JOIN drinks v on d.id = v.id
WHERE      v.ingredient = "vodka"
```

**Update:** Making this better correspond to the tables in question.  This is saying: given all of the vodka ingredients, find all of the ingredients that are found in the same drink as that vodka ingredient.

```
SELECT     d.*
FROM       drinks_ing d
INNER JOIN drinks_ing v on d.did = v.did
WHERE      v.ing = "vodka"
```

Comment: im not sure if this is compatible with how im getting the ratings, and also how i need to get all the ingredients back as a JSON string

Comment: I think you should worry first about gathering the data of interest, and only once you have that aspect of the query down, THEN worry about formatting it for JSON.  You should take a divide and conquer approach to your problem; solve one thing at a time.

Comment: Yes, I'm simplifying from your table structure; I did this to make clear to you how a self join works.  You will need to adapt this technique to work with your more elaborate table structure.  Do you understand what a self join is and why it would be relevant to your question?

Comment: I think im just not understanding what you're saying. I'm not really a SQL guy. so, I tried `FROM drinks a INNER JOIN drinks_ing c ON a.id = c.did where c.ing=1` (1 is vodka) and Im still JUST getting the vodka ingredient back.

Comment: Alright i think i understood what you're saying just enough because its working now! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in one query.  Your inn

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.descrip, a.type, CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT('{\"ing\":', c.ing, ',\"parts\":', c.parts, '}'), ']') ing
FROM drinks a LEFT JOIN drinks_ing c
     ON a.id = c.did
WHERE a.id in (select distinct a.id
                from drinks_ing c
                     ON a.id = c.did
                where c.ing = "vodka"
               )
```

This finds the drinks with the ingredient you want and returns information about the drinks.

Comment: To explain in a little more detail: The subquery gets the IDs for all the drinks that have vodka as an ingredient, and the outer query select all ingredients for those drinks.

Comment: Sorry thise method isn't compatible with everything I need it to do. for example getting ALL the ingredients, as well as getting the average rating and associating it with that particular row. I never heard of `distinct` before so, i tried simply including that right after the select in my subquery in the same query i posted above, but it did not work. it only returns the ingredient i searched for. Does my overall question make sense? maybe I could try and re-word it. sorry, its a bit complicated to explain.